# Adjacency algebra of asymmetric graph

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

What can be said about the adjacency algebra (or coherent algebra) of an asymmetric graph? Is it always $M_n(\mathbb{C})$? If not, what's a counterexample?

Comment: What do you means by asymmetric? Directed? No automorphisms?

Comment: I meant trivial automorphism group. Is there any easy description of the adjacency algebra of such a graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are asymmetric strongly regular graphs on 25 vertices, and larger, and the adjacency algebra of an srg has dimension three.

The adjacency algebra of a graph on $n$ vertices has dimension at most $n$, use Cayley-Hamilton to show that if $k\ge0$, then $A^n$ is a linear combination of the first $n$ powers of $A$. So trivial cases aside you never get the full matrix algebra.

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you very much.